# Is there a CSS selector to locate the 2nd/3rd child or descendant (of a given class/id) under an element (with a given class/id)?

Tags: css, xpath, selenium, css-selectors

I have something along the lines of this

```
<div class="menu" style="background-color: transparent;">
 <div class="button">
  <div class="divider" style="background-color: transparent;"></div>
  <a id="apple" class="unselect select" href="/apple">
   <span class="apple1">Apple</span>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="button">
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <a id="orange" class="unselect" href="/orange">
   <span class="orange1">Orange</span>
  </a>
 </div>
 ....
```

this gives me the first divider

```
css=div.menu div.button div.divider
```

I am trying to access the 2nd divider. I have the need to access the buttons as well. I tried reading through the the **nth child** stuff and noticed that it is not compatible with IE.

Is there a CSS selector to locate the 2nd/3rd child or descendant (of a given class/id) under an element (with a given class/id)?

I am using xPaths now

```
//div[@class='menu']/descendant::div[contains(@class,'divider')][2]
```

it works but I want to migrate this to CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
div.menu div.button + div.button div.divider{
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sandeep, that works great. I ended with one last one.. I now have 2 elements with class=divider under the last button element (both are siblings). How can I access the 2nd divider element (technically it is the 4th divider descendant of the top menu element)                                                             <div class="button">
<div class="divider" style="background-color: transparent;"></div>
<a id="Banana" class="unselect" href="/Banana">
<span class="heading5a">Originals</span>
</a>
<div class="divider" style="margin-left:165px;"></div>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

The [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) `+` is able to do that and is compatible with IE7+

Fiddle demonstrating its use with 4 buttons: **http://jsfiddle.net/AgNwu/**
(no need for "div" if you rely already on id/class everywhere. If you call something "button", expect it to be a link, an input[type="submit|image|button|reset"] or button element ;) )

**CSS**

```
.menu > .button {
    border: 1px solid darkblue;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.menu > .button + .button .divider {
    background: Tan;
}
.menu > .button + .button .divider:after{
    content: " (2nd or more)";
}

.menu > .button + .button + .button .divider {
    background: yellow;
}
.menu > .button + .button + .button .divider:after{
    content: " (3rd or more)";
}
```

edit: *adjacent* sibling, I thought this was sibling vs. general sibling
You can replace `+` by `~` (general sibling) if you have other type of nodes in-between your `.button` nodes/elements. This'd be the equivalent of `:nth-of-type` that would still work in IE7+

Comment: Thank you Felipe. Your link is very useful.... I am just starting with CSS for my selenium scripts.